# Aligning text and image in header using fancyhdr in LaTeX

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have tried the following to try to have the text on the right side on the header exactly at the same height of the center of the image in the left side of the same header:

```
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{MontajeLogo}}
\rhead{\textbf{University name}}
```

And I also tried using tabular like the following:

```
\fancyhead[L]{
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{MontajeLogo} & & University name \\
\end{tabular}}
```

But it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippets -- as usual here -- compilable. Then we can copy the code and test it on our computer ...

Comment: @PaulRoberts -- did the answer suit your requirement

Comment: Sure! Thank you @jsbibra

Comment: @PaulRoberts  -- would you like to accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\headheight=60pt
\rhead{%
        \Centerstack[l]{Foo bar \\
                        Baz lorem \\
                        ipsum dolor
        }
    }
\chead{}
\lhead{This should be vertically aligned (middle) \raisebox{-.4\height}
{\includegraphics[scale=0.016]{DD.jpg}}}

\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```